# Making a realistic canvas material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

How could I make a canvas shader in Cycles as shown in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Hi. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @RayMairlot, I have an answer that Nicola gave me on the bottom of mine.

Comment: I'm aware of that. My point is, on this site we prefer questions where the user demonstrates that they have at least tried to accomplish the task. This is so that a) We can see where specifically in the process they fail (because this site focuses on specific questions with specific answers) and b) Reduces questions which can come across as "Do this for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether you are looking for a procedural way or a texture-based material would be fine.

If using textures is ok, there's a white fabric material on CC0Textures [here](https://cc0textures.com/view.php?tex=Fabric01) that you can use like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow! That seems perfect, thanks. I'm gonna use it in my project. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do much here. You can use a default material that is only a Diffuse BSDF shader and get pretty convincing results.

Canvas material has some reflectivity and surface texture, but these can be seen only in specific conditions - when there is a strong light source that is reflected while you are looking at the surface at a grazing angle and when you are looking at it from a close distance. It is not usually distinguishable in most renders, so simple diffuse material is an option. You could add a Glossy BSDF with some roughness and mix it with the Diffuse BSDF with Fresnel node using IOR of something like 1.3 - 1.5(acrylic coating) and add some bump using an image texture of some fabric or you could mix 2 Wave Textures rotated at 90° angle to each other. This is not visible in your reference photo so you probably do not need that.